# Calculation of expectation of Poisson Process.

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables, poisson-process

[image]

This is a problem related to Poisson Process where $\lambda = 2$.

$
E(N_3N_4)    \\
= E[N_3(N_4-N_3 + N_3)]  \\
= E[N_3(N_4-N_3) + N^2_3)]  \\
= E[N_3 - N_0(N_4-N_3) + N^2_3)]  \\
= E[N_3 - N_0(N_4-N_3)] + E(N^2_3)]  \\ 
= E[N_3  N_1] + E(N^2_3)]  \\ 
= E[N_3] E[ N_1] + E(N^2_3)]  \\  
= ...
$

I haven't understood this.

Where does $N_0$ suddenly come from, and how did it accommodate itself with a minus sign beside $N_3$?

Where did $N_1$ come from?

How did $E[N_3  N_1]$ become $E[N_3]E[N_1]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Poisson process is a Lévy process. We know that its increments are independent and stationary. This means that if $N_t$ is a Poisson process with intensity $\lambda$ then $\forall t \geq s$
\begin{align*}
N_t - N_s \text{ is independent of} \, N_s   \\
N_t - N_s \sim \mathcal{P}(\lambda(t-s))
\end{align*}
Suppose that $\lambda = 2$. Let us compute $E[N_4N_3]$
\begin{align}
E[N_4N_3] &= E[N_3(N_4-N_3) + N_3^2] \\
&=E[N_3]E[N_4-N_3] + E[N_3^2] \\
&=2.3.2.(4-3) + 2.3 + (2.3)^2 \\
&= 54
\end{align}
Where the second equality holds due to the independent increments.

Comment: If you can write $E[N_3(N_4-N_3)] = E[N_3]E[N_4-N_3]$ why didn't you do $E[N_4N_3] = E[N_4]E[N_3]$ before?

Comment: So the random variable $N_3$ is independent of the random variable $(N_4 - N_3)$. That's why I wrote $E[N_3(N_4-N_3)] = E[N_3]E[(N_4-N_3)]$. I cannot see why $E[N_4N_3] = E[N_4]E[N_3]$.

Comment: How did u find the values $12 + 6 + 36$?

Comment: I recall that $N_t$ is a Poisson process with parameter $\lambda t$. Hence, $E[N_t] = \lambda t$ and $Var[N_t] = \lambda t$. In our problem $\lambda = 2$, we have then $E[N_3] =2.3 = 6$ and $E[N_4-N_3] = 2$. Finally, I recall that $Var[N_t] = E[N_t^2] - E[N_t]^2 =  2t$ which gives us  $ E[N_t^2] = 2t + (2t)^2$. Replacing t by 3 in the previous equation will have 6 + 36.